# Generic Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), msg) marked as nullable

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable, nullable-reference-types, activator

I have this generic method for throwing different exceptions with a different `T` depending on the context:

```
    private static T ThrowException<T>(string message) where T : Exception, new()
    {
        T? exception = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), message) as T;          
        throw exception;
    }
```

The `Activator.CreateInstance()` returns a `Nullable<T>` instead of `T`, therefore I get a possible null warning on `var exception`.

I can't think of a situation where the `var exception` could possibly end up being null. It seems like the `T : Exception` constraint is not considered by the compiler, because all the `T` I can possibly pass must extend `Exception`, otherwise, I'll see an error given the constraint.

Even though I could solve the warning by doing an extra null check and returning a generic `throw Exception` if `exception == null`, I'd rather much prefer to do so only if this is really going to be a possible situation. If not, I'd rather just suppress the warning with a null forgiving operator (`!`).

Is there any scenario where `exception` can be null?
If not, does it make logical sense to fix the warning instead of suppressing it (which seems to be a bad practice)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would definitely use `!` if it can't be null. I'm not an Activator expert tho.

Comment: Have you checked the value of typeOf(T)? Verify the namespace and it’s not private

Comment: What do you mean? Which value? I am passing an ArgumentNullException as T. I'm using reflection to create an instance of it from scratch.
If you talk about the message, this is non-nullable, so it's assumed to be not null by the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

As it's stated in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/23774#discussion_r354785674) pull request, `CreateInstance` method returns null only when called for `Nullable<T>` types, so in your case exception can never be null.

And btw you should probably use `(T)` cast instead of `as T` since you already know that returned value is T.

Comment: Then what is the reason why it is marked as nullable since the type I’m calling it for is not nullable?

Comment: It returns `object?`, so basically anything, and that includes null. It can be null, just not in your case.

Comment: I get the idea but I don't get why is my T return type nullable since it isn't supposed to be null in my case. Are confirming that in this case, the compiler is wrong? Can you go expand a little further?

Comment: Since you are not working with generic `CreateInstance` method, compiler doesn't know the return type, and it must cover every possible situation for every type passed. It warns you because function returns `object?`, compiler has no idea what can be there at the moment.